# Is there a way to include additional files in the most recent git commit?

Tags: git

A switch, for example, to include a few extra files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not yet pushed your local branch to the remote, then `git commit --amend` should come in handy:

```
git commit --amend 'Old commit message + added some new files'
```

Keep in mind that this is *rewriting* the history of the branch.  In particular, it is changing the commit at the HEAD of your local branch, thereby giving it a new SHA-1 hash.  So this option might not be the best idea if you have already pushed the branch out.

If you need to add files to a commit other than the latest one, then you can consider using `git rebase -i`, which is rebase in interactive mode.  But this is a much more involved endeavor.

Answer (score 0):

There's `git commit --amend`, which of course you should only use if you haven't pushed the previous commit anywhere yet.

Other than that, there's no convention other than "Whoops" that I'm aware of. Though you should consider force-pushing if you're 100% certain that the remote hasn't changed and that nobody has pulled from it just yet.

Comment: Does this keep my original commit message?

Comment: @Chris It gives you the option to edit the commit message.

Comment: It will keep the original commit message, unless you prompt it with a new one, using `git commit --amend -m 'New Message'`

Comment: "that the remote hasn't changed": You mean, that no one has pulled from the remote already? Force-pushing is very dangerous. I'd let it go and go with "Whoops" if the incomplete commit has already been pushed out.

Comment: There is a convention, `git commit --fixup`. Go and `man git-commit`.